# Implementation of inits using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I have to implement inits via foldr using map. I got most of it, however I'm missing the empty list element in my result list.

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr ( \ x y -> [x] : (map (x:) y) ) []
```

When called this results in:

> *Blueprint< inits [1,2,3]
>
> [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

I am a bit stuck now and would be glad if someone could point me in the general direction of my error.

Thanks in advance

Solved:

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr ( \ x y -> [] : (map (x:) y) ) [[]]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To write something with `foldr f z` you need to think about two things:

1. the base case `z`: what should `inits []` be?
2. the recursive step `f`: if you have a list `xs == x:xs'`, how can you construct `inits xs` from `x` and `y == inits xs'`?

---

Working through some small examples on paper might help. e.g.

- compute `inits [1]` recursively: you have `x == 1` and `y == inits [] == [[]]` and need to get to `[[], [1]]`.
- compute `inits [1, 2]` recursively: you have `x == 1` and `y == inits [2] == [[], [2]]` and need to get to `[[], [1], [1, 2]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it after thinking in the mentioned direction a bit more :)

Answer (score 8):

A more compact solution:

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr ((([] :) .) . map . (:)) [[]]
```

Comment: Holy punctuation, batman! Unfortunately we were required to use above pattern for the function by our prof :D