# Implementing tails using foldr in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

So earlier today I asked about [implementing inits via foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118741/implementation-of-inits-using-foldr/24120775#24120775). I have a similar question for tails now.
First things first: I have A solution. However it's not the solution I need, but the solution I deserve. Or something like that:

Code:

```
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = foldr ( \ x y ->  reverse([] : reverse(map (x:) y) )) [[]]
```

This provides correct results, however it does not fulfill the pattern our prof set for us. The pattern looks like this:

```
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = foldr ( \ x y -> undefined : undefined ) undefined
```

So obviously my function needs tweaking, however I do not get my head around it, since I always fall back to my solution.

Any tips on how to solve this better?

Thanks in advance.

*Solved:*

```
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = foldr ( \ x y -> (x : (head y)) : y) [[]]
```

Comment: Hint: With your professor's pattern, at each step, `y` needs to be equal to `tails xs` where `xs` is the part of the original list to the right of `x`, and `undefined : undefined` must be something that uses `x` and `y` to build the right value for `tails (x:xs)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some hints:

- You know that `tails [] == [[]]`, so your initial value has to be `[[]]`, so you'll have

  `tails = foldr (\x y -> undefined : undefined) [[]]`
- `length (tails xs !! n) > length (tails xs !! (n+1))`, or in plain english: the length of each tail gets shorter as you go down the list.
- What do you think about `foldr (\x (y:ys) -> undefined : undefined) [[]]`?

If you get stuck after a while again (or have already thought of these), leave a comment and I'll give you another nudge.

Comment: The accumulator value is no problem. My problem is, that I have to append an item at the front of the list (namely either x or [], since y is not the correct type). That just throws me off somehow. It's fine for the innermost iteration (the rightmost value of the given list and the accumulater), but past that I'm just buffled

Comment: @powlomat That's mainly what my last hint is about.  If you pattern match on your accumulator (`y`) as `y:ys` instead, then `y :: [a]`, `x :: a`, and `ys :: [[a]]`.  What all can you do with that?

Comment: Yeah I would love to do that, but it results in a not accepted pattern match (in the correction tool we use) :( I'm just allowed to replace the "undefined" terms, not anything else :/

Comment: @powlomat Then substitute in `head y` and `tail y` for `y` and `ys` respectively, if you're allowed to use those functions.

Comment: Thanks man, I was able to utilize this to solve it. Will update the question

Answer (score 3):

Sidenote, its interesting to me that the Haskell community on this site generally don't like to give flat answers, so I guess I will follow the trend (also the OP did not ask for a flat out answer)

Here are some hints:

- `foldr` folds from right to left
- Look at the output of `tails "abc"`, it's `["abc", "bc", "c", ""]`. How do you construct the list going from right to left? (or in other words, prepending things to the list)
- What is the difference between the elements of the result, looking from right to left?  Is there a pattern?

Comment: I think that's because if a question comes across as homework, hints result in more learning for the student than something you can copy and compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I seem to be seeing unfolds everywhere of late, including in this question:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = unfoldr (\ xs -> listToMaybe xs >> Just (xs, tail xs))
```

Comment: That seems an awfully awkward use of `listToMaybe`. How about `tails = unfoldr (\ xs -> do {(_ : tl) <- return xs; return (xs, tl)})` instead?

Comment: Perhaps better: Define `uncons [] = Nothing`, `uncons (x:xs) = Just (x,xs)` (this may be in a library somewhere, but I'm only finding it for `Text` and `ByteString` and things). Then use `tails = unfoldr (\xs -> uncons xs >>= \(_, tl) -> Just (xs, tl))`

Comment: There's a serious problem: `tails` is not an unfold; there's just no way to get the empty tail. We want `unfold f [] = [[]]` which means that `f [] = Just ([], something)`, but then `f something` must be `Nothing`, and there's no actual list that can be used for `something`!

Comment: Ah yes, that's true, (the empty list case).

Comment: @dfeuer as we've [found out few weeks later](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24519530/849891), it *can* be done with apomorphism; which can be simulated by a standard unfoldr with a nested `Maybe`. I guess that's how you came up with that question, maybe.