# Slightly generalizing unfold

Tags: haskell

`Data.List` defines

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
unfoldr f b = case f b of
  Just (a,new_b) -> a : unfoldr f new_b
  Nothing -> []
```

There are a number of functions that can almost be defined using `unfoldr`, but have trouble at the very end of the list. A simple "fix" is

```
unfoldr' :: (b -> Either (a,b) [a]) -> b -> [a]
unfoldr' f b = case f b of
  Left (a, new_b) -> a : unfoldr' f new_b
  Right r         -> r
```

Does this function have a standard name? Does it have nice properties and interact well with `foldr`?

Comment: What is an example of a function that is difficult to define with `unfoldr` but easy with `unfoldr'`?

Comment: @amalloy, consider `f xs = zip (map reverse $ inits xs) (tails xs)`.

Comment: You can implement `unfoldr'` in terms of `unfold` if `b` is an `Either`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, that's a good point. Do you think it will be equally efficient?

Comment: @dfeuer I'm probably missing something as I'm no haskell expert, but I couldn't see how to use `unfoldr'` to make a better definition of `f`. `let g xs = ([],xs) : unfoldr go ([], xs) where {go (_, []) = Nothing; go (as, (b:bs)) = Just ((b:as, bs), (b:as, bs))}` looks about the same as `let h xs = unfoldr' go ([], xs) where {go (xs, []) = Right [(xs, [])]; go (as, (b:bs)) = Left ((as, b:bs), (b:as, bs))}`

Comment: If the main problem is that you want to be able to produce multiple result items per seed (as your `Right [a]` allows you to), you could simply define `unfoldr' f xs = concat $ unfoldr f xs`, to allow that behavior at any point instead of just at the end of the result list.

Comment: @amalloy, you may be right about my example (and I thank you for that), but your `concat` notion looks a bit off. List ends are shared so if just the end is special, it probably makes sense to special-case it.

Comment: @dfeuer I estimate that it should be roughly the same efficiency (i.e. within a factor of 2) because neither one is recursive and `ghc` tends to optimize fairly deterministically for non-recursive code.

Comment: It reminds me a little bit of something I called `generalFold`: http://pastebin.com/r7jdBVDM (that's not my pastebin, but I think that's the only place my code for `generalFold` is online right now). The `Left` and `Right` are reversed from what you have to take advantage of the `Either` monad and it's also more analogous to how `Maybe` is used in the typical `unfoldr` (both `Nothing` and `Left ...` traditionally represent failure, so they correspond to termination).

Comment: better to name it `unfoldrn` following [Richard Bird's `foldrn`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Special_folds_for_non-empty_lists) which also deals with the end ("n-th element") specially.

Comment: so, to recap, `b->Maybe (a,b) ~= b->Either (a,b) ()` (`()` producing  an empty `[a]`), which is `< b->Either (a,b) [a]`. The latter is also reminiscent of the `VIP` structure from "implicit heaps" in primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this is more of a comment, with some code so it doesn't fit) Consider the test case that you mention in the comments,

```
f xs -- = zip (map reverse $ inits xs) (tails xs)
  = unfoldr g (Just ([],xs))
      where
        g (Just (acc,xs@[]))    = Just ( (acc,xs), Nothing)
        g (Just (acc,xs@(x:t))) = Just ( (acc,xs), Just (x:acc, t) )
        g Nothing = Nothing
```

the perceived problem is with the one extra processing beat to *end* the list, which forces us to use the nested `Maybe`. Indeed it's easier with your function (there's no need for the nested `Maybe`):

```
  = unfoldr' h ([],xs)
      where
        h (acc,xs@[])    = Right [ (acc,xs) ]    -- last tail
        h (acc,xs@(x:t)) = Left  ( (acc,xs), (x:acc,t) )
```

But we could also simplify the `g` code another way:

```
  = unfoldr (fmap g') (Just ([],xs))
      where
        g' (acc,xs@[])    = ( (acc,xs), Nothing)   -- last element
        g' (acc,xs@(x:t)) = ( (acc,xs), Just (x:acc, t) )
```

and use this as a skeleton for such functions, with the standard `unfoldr` still. Or maybe one more `Nothing` line of code in the definition of `g` is, well, nothing to be concerned about.

But of course it's no replacement in the case where you really need to put a special tail into your list, not just one more element.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [elgot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v%3aelgot) from recursion-schemes, I think.

Expanding and looking again, it might just be `apo` from the same package.  That function has type `(Unfoldable t, Foldable t) => (a -> Base t (Either t a)) -> a -> t`.  Renaming `a` to `b` and taking `t` as `[a]` we get `(b -> Base [a] (Either [a] b)) -> b -> [a]`.

Looking at the `Base [a] (Either [a] b)` part requires referencing the source code, but gives us a data family with only a few constructors: `Cons a (Left [a])`, `Cons a (Right b)`, and `Nil`.  Now your type, `Either (a, b) [a]` also has only a few constructors: `Left (a, b)`, `Right (a:[a])`, and `Right []`.  I think you can see that there is an isomorphism between the two types.  Here's one side:

```
e2pe :: Either (a, b) [a] -> Prim [a] (Either [a] b)
e2pe (Left  (x,y)) = Cons x $ Right y
e2pe (Right (x:xs))  = Cons x $ Left xs
e2pe (Right [])    = Nil
```

My (unproven) claim is that `unfoldr' f` = `apo $ e2pe . f`.

Here's some tests, after defining your `unfoldr'` and my `e2pe`:

```
GHCi> let f n = case compare n 0 of { EQ -> Right []; LT -> Left (n, succ n); GT -> Left (n, pred n); }
GHCi> unfoldr' f 5
[5,4,3,2,1]
GHCi> apo (e2pe . f) 5
[5,4,3,2,1]
GHCi> unfoldr' f (-5)
[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1]
GHCi> apo (e2pe . f) (-5)
[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1]
GHCi> let f n = case compare n 0 of { EQ -> Right [0]; LT -> Left (n, succ n); GT -> Left (n, pred n); }
GHCi> unfoldr' f 5
[5,4,3,2,1,0]
GHCi> unfoldr' f (-5)
[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0]
GHCi> apo (e2pe . f) 5
[5,4,3,2,1,0]
GHCi> apo (e2pe . f) (-5)
[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0]
```

If my claim is correct, you've reinvented the apomorphism.

Comment: The documentation for that function seems to be suffering from an existence failure, and its source code requires more than I know to understand.

Comment: Agreed.  http://comonad.com/reader/2008/elgot-coalgebras/ is a descent reference.