# What does (x:) mean in haskell

Tags: haskell

What does the x: mean in this Code

[Implementation of inits using foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118741/implementation-of-inits-using-foldr?newreg=1c5df991e235404b9bad42fd3bd2d12f)

```hs
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr ( \ x y -> [] : (map (x:) y) ) [[]]
```

Comment: It's a function which takes a list (whose items are the same type as `x`) and outputs the same list with `x` added at the start.

Comment: it's `(x :)`. Parens are essential, whitespace is optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a function of a single argument that `cons`es `x` to some list:

```
(x:) [] => [x]
(x:) [1, 2] => [x, 1, 2]
```

Here "`cons`es" means "prepends a value to some list". `cons` is the "canonical" name of a function that does this. So, the `:` function is the `cons` function.

Answer (score 6):

This is an effect of the [*infix operator sectioning* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator):

> `(2^)` (left section) is equivalent to `(^) 2`, or more verbosely `\x -> 2 ^ x`

So `(x:)` is short for `(:) x`, or `\y -> x : y`. The "*cons*" `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` is a function that takes an element (type `a`) and a list (type `[a]`) and constructs a list with the element followed by the elements in the list.

`(x:) :: [a] -> [a]` is thus a function that takes a list and prepends that list with `x`.

We can make the fold function "*point free*" with:

```
foldr (((:) [] .) . map . (:)) [[]]
```